# $W$ is $T$-invariant and showing that $W = N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I got a problem with this question:

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be linear, and assume that $W$ is a subspace of the vectorspace $V$. Then suppose that $V = R(T) \oplus W$ and $W$ is $T$-invariant.

1) Show that if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $W = N(T)$.

2) Show by example that the conclusion of (1) is not necessarily true if $V$ is not finite-dimensional.

**Attempt at a solution:**

1) Because we know that $W$ and $R(T)$ are subspaces of $V$, so we know they are finite dimensional aswell. Thus $\dim(V) = \dim(R(T) \oplus W) = \dim(R(T) + \dim(W) - \dim(R(T) \cap W)$. But by definition of direct sum: $\dim(R(T) \cap W) = 0$. Hence $\dim(V) = \dim(R(T)) + \dim(W)$.

From the Dimension Theorem, we have $\dim(V) = \operatorname{nullity}(T) + \operatorname{rank}(T)$. So can I just equate this equation now with the previous one and state that $\operatorname{nullity}(T) = \dim(W)$, and hence $W = N(T)$?

And for 2) I got no idea, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the first one, you only showed that $W \cong N(T)$, not necessarily equality.

Comment: How would that be, care to elaborate? How should I improve?

Comment: You didn't use the invariance of $T$, which is important for this question. You merely exhibited the fact that $\dim W = \dim N(T).$

Comment: What if I assume $W \subset N(T)$ (which is easy to prove) and in combination with $dim(W) = dim(V) - dim(R(T))$. Then I can conclude that $W = N(T)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is not off. Since $W$ and $N(T)$ have the same dimension, it suffices you show one is included in the other, in either direction. Given $w\in W$, note that $Tw\in W\cap R(T)$, so $Tw=0$. This means $W\subseteq N(T)$.

Consider now $k[X]$ for some field $k$, and define $p(X)\mapsto p'(X)$. Then ${\rm im}\;T=k[X]$ so $k[X]=R(T)\oplus 0$, but the kernel of this is nonempty.

Comment: Why is Im $T = k[X]$ ?

Comment: @Kamil Given a polynomial $p(X)$; there is always a polynomial $P(X)$ for which $P'(X)=p(X)$, isn't there?

Comment: Right. So you just mean: $T: P_n (R) \rightarrow P_{n-1}(R)$ defined by $ T(f(x)) = f'(x)$. But how is that going to work when $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: @Kamil No, I didn't mean that. Take the *infinite* dimensional vector space of polynomials $k[X]$, and consider the map that sends any polynomial to its derivative. But of course, you can restrict $T$ to $k_n[X]$ for any $n$.

Comment: Ok thanks, got it now. Merry xmas!